# Is there any callback when form has been validated

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate a form, but I have a complicated requirement.

I have to enable/disable a button which is not in the same form, but at the bottom of the page. Is there any callback when form has been validated?

Comment: Yes, `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler`. See the docs: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for your suggestions, but these two callbacks are fired when a user tries to submit the form. What I want is to get a callback the moment it got validated.

Comment: And how are you expecting the whole form to validate without clicking the submit?

Answer (score 1):

Quote user comment:

> *"Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for your suggestions, but these two callbacks are fired when a user tries to submit the form. What I want is to get a callback the moment it got validated."*

Yes, because submitting the form is what triggers validation of the entire form.  "*The moment it (the form) got validated*" is not something you can capture otherwise.

**There are no callbacks for this.**

You can capture when an individual field is validated via `focusout` and `keyup` events, and you can capture when the whole form is validated via the `click` event of the submit button.  But you cannot capture when the entire form is valid without using the submit button or programmatically triggering validation on the whole form.

---

However, there is a function that counts the total number of errors called `this.numberOfInvalids()`.  And there is a callback that fires whenever any field is evaluated called [`showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).  You can use `showErrors` to construct a possible (imperfect) workaround.  Count how many error messages, and when there are more than zero, you know the form is invalid.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    if (this.numberOfInvalids() != 0) {
        // invalid form
    } else {
        // no errors
    }
    this.defaultShowErrors(); // enable default error messages
}
```

However, when there are zero errors, the form might or might not be valid;   **this solution does not cover all cases and will fail if the user has not yet clicked the submit button**.  When the user has not yet clicked the submit button, blank inputs can not yet be counted as errors.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/fL6n4oub/](https://jsfiddle.net/fL6n4oub/)**

Perhaps you can get creative and find a solution using some of what I've shown here.

---

*You could construct your own custom event handler function that triggers on the `focusout` and `keyup` events of all fields, but the only available method for testing the entire form's validity will also cause the form's validation messages to appear.*

Comment: Thanks mate.! I'll try this.